# Progressive web app in offline is not working with Angular Js 1.5.x

Tags: angularjs, service-worker

I am trying to create a progressive web app using angular 1.5 with help of gulp.

I have created a service worker(sw.js) using sw-precache module in npm.

this is my index.html

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html ng-app="ngapp">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>sfxInstantPay</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#CA3F39">
    <link rel="manifest" type="text/css" href="app/manifest.json">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->

    <!-- build:css({.tmp/serve,src}) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <!-- run `gulp inject` to automatically populate bower styles dependencies -->
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:css({.tmp/serve,src}) styles/app.css -->
    <!-- inject:css -->
    <!-- css files will be automatically insert here -->
    <!-- endinject -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            // Path is relative to the origin, not project root.
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('scripts/sw.js')
            .then(function(reg) {
                console.log('Registration succeeded. Scope is ' + reg.scope);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.error('Registration failed with ' + error);
            });
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!--[if lt IE 10]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <div ui-view="app" layout-fill></div>

    <!-- build:js(src) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <!-- run `gulp inject` to automatically populate bower script dependencies -->
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js({.tmp/serve,.tmp/partials,src}) scripts/app.js -->
    <!-- inject:js -->
    <!-- js files will be automatically insert here -->
    <!-- endinject -->

    <!-- inject:partials -->
    <!-- angular templates will be automatically converted in js and inserted here -->
    <!-- endinject -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

  </body>
</html>
```

I am using UI router to make route changes . my router.js is

```
    (function() {
    'use strict';

     angular
    .module('ngapp')
    .config(routerConfig);

     /** @ngInject */
     function routerConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
     $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/index.html',
        views:{
          'app@':{
            templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/xx/views/xx.html',
            controller: 'xxController',
            controllerAs: 'xCtrl'
          }
        }

      });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/index.html');
    }

    })();
```

and my manifest.json is

```
    {
    "name": "Hello Mobile",
    "icons": [
    {
      "src": "assets/images/angular.png",
      "sizes": "100x100",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
    ],
    "start_url": "/index.html",
     "display": "standalone",
     "orientation": "portrait",
     "theme_color": "#000000",
    "background_color": "#e0e0e0"
    }
```

in gulp build file I am generating sw.js file by below code

```
    gulp.task('generate-service-worker-dist', function(callback) {
    var path = require('path');
    var swPrecache = require('sw-precache');
    var rootDir = path.join(conf.paths.dist,'');

    swPrecache.write(path.join(rootDir+'/scripts', 'sw.js'), {
    staticFileGlobs: [rootDir + '/**/*.{js,html,css,png,jpg,gif}'],
    stripPrefix: rootDir
    }, callback);
    });
```

After I ran gulp buld application is running normal service worker is created and in Application tab developer console I can see service worker activated and running. but When I goto offline and refresh the page it is not opening

Please tell me where is my mistake.

Comment: what clues do you find in browser dev tools? Are all the libs included in `sw.js`?

Comment: Yes, All resources are loaded. But in console I found this   Registration succeeded. Scope is http://localhost:3000/scripts/

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because the sw can't fetch the request the browser is asking for.
Verify the following:

- Place the sw in the same scope as the main page (index.html), probably this is the error, because the sw scope is http://localhost:3000/scripts and the main request is http://localhost:3000/index.html
- Look in the **cache storage** (chrome) if there is an entry for your main request, e.g. http://locahost:3000/ or http://locahost:3000/index.html depending on your main entry point.

This two points should be true in order to the application can go offline.

Comment: Thanks . This is one of the issue.  I found the problem . sw.js file is generating before all html,js and image files. I fixed this problem and it is working fine now.